# Autofill function error

Tags: excel, vba

I currently facing an error of Application defined error for autofill function. Please tell me where I did wrong

```
Sheet9.Range("B10").AutoFill Destination:=Sheet9.Range("B11:B17"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this...

```
Sheet9.Range("B10").AutoFill Destination:=Sheet9.Range("B10:B17"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

You should include the source cell in the destination range.

Comment: Thanks ! Was thinking for quite long whats wrong with it